# How do I use a variable in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

I've got this problem i can't solve.
I want to make the part that says "aboutMe" a variable called page_name (after the parameter), but I can't get it working...

```
$(document).ready(function(page_name) {
$.getJSON('../json/text.json', function(obj) {
    // fill the title
    for(i in obj.titles) {
        var id1 = obj.titles[i].id;
        var title1 = obj.titles[i].title;
        $("#"+id1+"_title").append(title1);
    }
    // fill the rest of the page
    for(i in obj.pages.aboutMe.page_element) {
        var id = obj.pages.aboutMe.page_element[i].id;
        var title = obj.pages.aboutMe.page_element[i].title;
        var  content  = obj.pages.aboutMe.page_element[i].content;
        var left_content =  obj.pages.aboutMe.page_element[i].content_left;
        var  right_content  = obj.pages.aboutMe.page_element[i].content_right;
        $("#"+id+"_title").append(title);
        $("#"+id+"_content").append(content);
        $("#"+id+"_left_content").append(left_content);
        $("#"+id+"_right_content").append(right_content);
    }
    for(var i in obj.pages.study) {

    }
});
});
```

Does Anyone know how to solve this?
I would be very gratfull!

Comment: `obj.pages[page_name].page_element` ...though the `.ready()` callback isn't going to pass anything useful as a page name. `$(document).ready(function(page_name) {` ???

Comment: re:  @squint's comment:   @user2351350: do you intend to be using `(function(page_name){...})(globalvar);`  syntax?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error? Try using $(document).ready(function(){}); syntax. It may happen that there is a Jquery conflict. You can also resolve that by JQuery(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: No at the moment this code works, but where in the code is "aboutMe" I want to place a variable like "page_name"..

Comment: Can you show your html code as well so that we can have the page as well?